# Clearing ctx.fillStyle after drawing a filled rectangle

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Clearing ctx.fillStyle after drawing a filled rectangle doesn't work...

I've tried:

- `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out';`
- `ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` Clearing the canvas itself
- `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)";` Setting it to white
- `ctx.fillStyle = null;` Maybe nulling it will work...

But I got no result other than reDrawing its previous value and not the new one.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9ub0r9z/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`ctx.fillRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) instead, see updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q9ub0r9z/2/

Answer (score 0):

You use .fillRect function instead of .rect

```
function showRed(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0, 200, 200);
}
function showGreen(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,255,0,1)";
    ctx.fillRect(200,0, 200, 200);

}
function showBlue(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,255,1)";
    ctx.rect(200,200, 200, 200);
}
function showBlack(){
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,1)";
    ctx.rect(200,200, 400, 400);
}
```